# "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG" error

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, exception

Im trying to use ksoap2 with a webservice in android but I think i cannot get a respond from the webservice. Anyone knows why i get this error?
"org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG"

my code is:

```
public class ANDROIDsapActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.2.5:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/bndg_E0DFBFD4F407C3F1A6A000155D02060A/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=500";    
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "zws_get_customer";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "ZfGetCustomers";
        TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("IM_NAME","M");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        soapEnvelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2003;
        soapEnvelope.bodyOut = Request;
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;

       // AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
        headers.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization",  "basic " +
                Base64.encode("username:password".getBytes())));

        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope,headers);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            tv.setText("Status: " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            tv.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

my complete error is :

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG  
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/} Envelope  
(position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions  
targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sapsoap:functions:mc-style'>  
@1:630 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e50a10
```

I'm stuck in this error and I cant go any further.
Please help!

**EDIT: I HAVE SOLVED THIS. PLEASE READ MY ANSWER BELOW ON COMMENTS AND ANSWERS.
I HOPE I'LL BE HELPFUL FOR SOMEONE IN SOMEWAY.**

Comment: Please check your SOAP_ACTION.I think it should be `NAMESPACE+"/"+METHOD_NAME`. If this doesn't work then tell me I will help you further.

Comment: I still get the same error. I'm thinking that my URL doesnt work. Because in my webservice its not like my URL. Its not an IP but a web address. Do you think that it could be the problem?

Comment: Please check that if you fire the URL in browser it should return a `WSDL` or any message related to that service.

Comment: I have tried to change SOAP_ACTION but i think my error is not related to SOAP_ACTION because no matter what value I gave to SOAP_ACTION, I got the same exception/error. I even gave null to SOAP_ACTION and got the same error. My code stucks on this line :  aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope,headers);

Comment: Why are you using headers,is there any certificate used for authenticating some stuff?If not then don't use them.Otherwise you have to use HttpsTransportSE method for certification purpose.

Comment: @Shashank_Itmaster Thank you for your advice but SAP web services did not support to use SOAP system in somehow. As I have replied myself below RESTful webservice has solved my problem and it is working properly right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by just changing the web service style. Use Restful webservice system instead of SOAP if you want to integrate SAP and android.

Comment: hi mtu iam also getting same problem but i didnt understand what you are saying. iam facing this in android. please can you explain it in clear..

Comment: Hi sando, If you try to integrate a SAP web-service with android app, I believe you need to use RESTFUL type of webservice which is available in android, not SOAP. Please consider looking deeper in Restful Webservices in android.