# How to enable a SAP FM or BAPI for XML-RPC or SOAP access

Tags: soap, xml-rpc, saprfc, bapi

I just created a Function Module, made it Remote-Enabled, and now I want to invoke it via *XML-RPC* over HTTP. I'm on *SAP NetWeaver App Server ABAP v7*. What other configuration is required in order to expose my FM over XML-RPC? How do I configure the end-point URL and all that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several explanations on the subject in on SDN, as [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/f02b33fc-9eb1-2c10-0599-f2ef9fb5c5b6?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true) and [here](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Web+Service+provider+using+ABAP-RFC) which describe the generation of a webservice from a function module, and [here](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAPConn/Technical+Setup+and+Reset+of+the+Web+Service+Runtime), which describe the basic webservice configuration (ie SICF).

Comment: Actually the links offered above point to obsolete documents, but they helped me find the correct ones for the system version that I specifically asked. For anyone else who may be interested, you can find them [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp2/helpdata/en/e5/a68d10f4eb894087fc9c1c3f9ae433/frameset.htm)

Answer (score 0):

What concerns XML-RPC

No, this is not possible to directly call SAP FM in XML-RPC style. You have two workarounds:

1. Use SAP SOAP adapter for calling SOAP-enabled FMs
2. Make a SOAP wrapper for your XML-RPC call in whatever programming environment you have. It is rather simple

What concerns SOAP

It is natively supported, there are plenty of [manuals](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/12/04/create-a-webservices-on-abap-from-a-function-module/) how to do it.